# nested query to show MAX price during the last month. whats wrong with my code?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT RegNo, Make, Model, Colour, dateSold
FROM CarForSale
WHERE (dateSold) Between #12/21/2016# And #1/21/2017# AND (Price =(SELECT MAX (Price)
FROM CarForSale));
```

the code above shows me blank fields, i know what the answer is supposed to be. I'm fairly new to using nested queries so any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: access,im really new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery needs the same date range as the outer query.

However, this might be easier with `top` and `order by`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RegNo, Make, Model, Colour, dateSold
FROM CarForSale
WHERE dateSold Between #12/21/2016# And #1/21/2017# 
ORDER BY Price DESC;
```

Comment: thank you very much :) so by putting in TOP that means I don't have to use a nested query statement with MAX